# Linux - Find string and then end of section

Tags: grep, sed, awk, perl

I have an XMLTV file.  I need to get all of the programme sections for a specific channel.   An example snippet:

```
    <programme start="2023031305000 -0400" end="2023031305300 -0400" channel="Bleah.us"
      <title>This is the Title</title>
      <desc>This is the Description</desc>
    </programme>
```

Simple enough if the programme section was always 4 lines: grep -A3 channel="Bleah.us"

But the programme section may change lengths.  Sometimes it may have addition sub-elements like <sub-title> and/or <category> and/or <icon>.

So my question.  How do I find the lines that contains 'channel="Bleah.us"' and print that line and all of the lines until '</programme>' is found (and print that line too)?
There could be 1 secion, there could be 100 sections, I won't know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide expected output. Text or XML? Consider using `xidel`, `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep`, `sed`, `awk` are not the tools to parse `XML`. Instead, use a proper `XML` parser:

##### With `xidel`:

```
$ cat file.xml
<root>
    <programme start="2023031305000 -0400" end="2023031305300 -0400" channel="Bleah.us"
      <title>This is the Title</title>
      <desc>This is the Description</desc>
    </programme>
    <programme start="2023031305000 -0400" end="2023031305300 -0400" channel="a"
      <title>This is the Title</title>
      <desc>This is the Description</desc>
    </programme>
    <programme start="2023031305000 -0400" end="2023031305300 -0400" channel="s"
      <title>This is the Title</title>
      <desc>This is the Description</desc>
    </programme>
</root>
```

```
$ xidel --output-node-format=xml -e '//programme[@channel="Bleah.us"]' file.xml
```

##### With `xmllint`:

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath '//programme[@channel="Bleah.us"]' file.xml 2>/dev/null
```

##### Output

```
<programme start="2023031305000 -0400" end="2023031305300 -0400" channel="Bleah.us" <title="">This is the Title
      <desc>This is the Description</desc>
    </programme>
```

Comment: Well, shoot - that it makes it soooo much easier!   I didn't have xidel as an option, but I was able to do the same thing with xmllint:

Comment: If your XML is well formated, yes

Comment: Added `xmllint` way